# Reactjs - × TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

> Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined. /node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42

I am getting this error when i run my react application along with an express backend. The application was running fine until the error surfaced from nowhere.

```
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 |
```

This is what I am getting in the console:

````
    at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:42)
    at Object../node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1142)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object../node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object../node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/actions/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/containers/HomeContainer.js (UserPosts.js:53)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/components/home/home.js (sidenav_items.js:80)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/routes.js (user_reducer.js:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/index.js (HomeContainer.js:42)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (BookItem.js:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1```
````

Comment: I assume you've done all the basic things like restarting, clearing node_modules and reinstalling etc etc. What's line 24 in BookItem.js?

Comment: It is a component that renders book items. It was among the first components i created and has been working all along.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your **webpack** config

```
target: 'node'
```